# What is the point of an RSS item without a link, and what do I do with it?

Tags: rss, rss-reader

According to the RSS spec https://www.rssboard.org/rss-draft-1#element-channel-item

> An item MAY contain the following child elements: author, category, comments, description, enclosure, guid, link, pubDate, source and title. All of these elements are OPTIONAL but an item MUST contain either a title or description.

If I'm building an RSS reader, what exactly am I supposed to do with an item without a link? What even is the point of listing such an item?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you assume that a link is required? Just show everything as normal, but don't have a link to anything.